# How to find possible combination of keys having sum of values equal or greater than k using dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1= {"Noodles":20, "Burger":10, "Sandwitch":20}
d2= {"Pepsi": 20, "Coke": 25, "Soup": 15, "Sprite":10}
dic = {**d1, **d2}
keys = dic.keys()

import itertools
all_comb = list(itertools.combinations(keys, 4))

for val in all_comb:
    lt = list(val)
    sum = dic[lt[0]] + dic[lt[1]] + dic[lt[2]] + dic[lt[3]]
    if sum < 70:
        all_comb = all_comb.remove(val)
    else:
        continue
print(all_comb)
```

This code is displaying all the combination of keys, I want to display only the combinations having a sum of 70 or greater.

Comment: As a general rule, don't remove items from a list while iterating it. Build another one. In your case, you should filter directly when creating the list, while you iterate on `itertools.combinations(keys, 4)` - and don't create a list out of it first!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you remove items from the list while iterating on it. As a general rule, don't do that, you're going to miss items.
You should rather build a new list.

In your case, it is better to only keep the valid combinations while you iterate on the output of `itertools.combinations`. You should not use `list(itertools.combinations(...))`: this forces all possible combinations to be calculated and stored immediately, which you don't need, and is inefficient. The functions in `itertools` are, as the name of the module suggests, iterators. They generate their output values lazily, one by one.

Just do:

```
for combination in itertools.combinations(...):
    # check the combination and store it if valid
```

As a side note, avoid using the names of Python builtin functions (like `sum`) as variable names, as this shadows the original functions.

So, your code could be:

```
import itertools


d1= {"Noodles":20, "Burger":10, "Sandwitch":20}
d2= {"Pepsi": 20, "Coke": 25, "Soup": 15, "Sprite":10}
dic = {**d1, **d2}
keys = dic.keys()

valid_combinations = []
for comb in itertools.combinations(keys, 4):
    total = sum(dic[key] for key in comb)
    if total >= 70:
        valid_combinations.append(comb)
        
print(valid_combinations)
# [('Noodles', 'Burger', 'Sandwitch', 'Pepsi'), 
#  ('Noodles', 'Burger', 'Sandwitch', 'Coke'), 
#  ('Noodles', 'Burger', 'Pepsi', 'Coke'),
#  ('Noodles', 'Burger', 'Coke', 'Soup'),
 #  .... ]
```